# Why i can't delete the php file?

Tags: php, linux

There is php file in my server. I tried to delete it , But Permission denied. It was created by a php virus.

**root@host [/home/depotdeb/public_html]# ls -la hl**

total 12

```
d--------- 2 depotdeb depotdeb 4096 Jul 16 11:25 ./ 
drwxr-x--- 6 depotdeb depotdeb 4096 Jul 21 01:49 ../
-rwxrwxrwx 1 depotdeb depotdeb   89 Jul 21 01:48 index.php*
root@host [/home/depotdeb/public_html]# cd hl
root@host [/home/depotdeb/public_html/hl]# rm -f index.php
rm: cannot remove `index.php': Permission denied
```

**root@host [/home/depotdeb/public_html/hl]# lsattr index.php**

```
-------------e- index.php
root@host [/home/depotdeb/public_html/hl]# ls -la
total 12
d--------- 2 depotdeb depotdeb 4096 Jul 16 11:25 ./
drwxr-x--- 6 depotdeb depotdeb 4096 Jul 21 01:49 ../
-rwxrwxrwx 1 depotdeb depotdeb   89 Jul 21 01:48 index.php*
root@host [/home/depotdeb/public_html/hl]# chattr -i index.php
root@host [/home/depotdeb/public_html/hl]# lsattr index.php
-------------e- index.php
```

**root@host [/home/depotdeb/public_html/hl]# rm index.php**

```
rm: remove regular file `index.php'? y
rm: cannot remove `index.php': Permission denied
root@host [/home/depotdeb/public_html/hl]# cd ../
```

**root@host [/home/depotdeb/public_html]# chown depotdeb.depotdeb hl**

```
chown: changing ownership of `hl': Operation not permitted
```

**root@host [/home/depotdeb/public_html]# cd hl**

**root@host [/home/depotdeb/public_html/hl]# ls -il**

```
total 12
26620397 d--------- 2 depotdeb depotdeb 4096 Jul 16 11:25 ./
  533919 drwxr-x--- 6 depotdeb depotdeb 4096 Jul 21 01:49 ../
26620398 -rwxrwxrwx 1 depotdeb depotdeb   89 Jul 21 01:48 index.php*
```

**root@host [/home/depotdeb/public_html/hl]#**

Comment: Does the file have an ACL that's overriding the basic permissions?

Comment: Do you have `write` permissions on the `hl` _folder_?

Answer (score 3):

According to this:

```
d--------- 2 depotdeb depotdeb 4096 Jul 16 11:25 ./
```

you don't have write permissions to the folder `hl`, where the file is located. Try this:

```
cd /home/depotdeb/public_html
chmod 755 ./hl
#unset the immutable bit for the folder:
chattr -i ./hl
rm /home/depotdeb/public_html/hl/index.php
```

Comment: @Cattla maybe, this will help: http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?t=63363